# Unde "-cundus"?

Tags: etymology, participle, adjective, suffixes

I have learned that there is a suffix *-cundus,* found in words like *fecundus, jucundus/jocundus,* and *rubicundus,* which means something like "full of" or "characterized by." It seems to often be mentioned along with participles ending in *-ndus* and *-bundus* (such as  Allen and Greenough's [New Latin Grammar](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.253.html)).

Apparently, it is of "disputed origin" (*[The Foundations of Latin](https://books.google.com/books?id=gWY7-DBWPW4C&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq=latin%20suffix%20cundus&source=bl&ots=_k_EHBlzB1&sig=JPrWKjAo56Z6AgbH7_FaLtBV8rE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsn_SCybXMAhXGmoMKHR2RCD4Q6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=latin%20suffix%20cundus&f=false),* Philip Baldi 1999) but I'm interested in learning what etymologies have been proposed.

I did find one paper that contains a summary of the current "state of the art": [«Une loi phonétique méconnue en latin : la lex-
*hircus*»](http://www.academia.edu/18792465/_Sur_les_para-participes_en_-cundus_du_latin_), by Romain Garnier (in French; I couldn't find the publication date but it must be recent since it has citations from 2015).

Garnier says Beneviste (1933) and Szemerényi (1950) proposed derivations from a PIE root **ḱuH-* meaning «être gonflé» ("to be swollen, inflated"), followed by a suffix (according to Beneviste, *-ond-ó-*; according to Szemerényi, *-tn-ó-*).

De Vaan (2015) is supposed to have proposed that the *c* is not part of the suffix at all, and that *fecundus* should be analyzed as *fec-undus* with the same stem as in the perfect *feci.*

Garnier himself argues that *facundus* comes from a form **bʰéh₂-tu-* followed by a group of suffixes **-u̯o-dn-ó*, which syncopated to **fātu̯ond-o,* and then assimilated to **fāqu̯ond-o* (which subsequently developed according to generally recognized sound laws).

I don't really know how to evaluate these etymologies. Which one is most widely accepted? Are there any others that I haven't found?

Comment: Weiss (Hist. Gramm. Latin 299) says "The suffix perhaps originated by misanalysis of *sec-undus* as *se-cundus*" (which strikes me as a little desperate). The fact that there are several disparate recent proposals suggests that there's no single widely accepted explanation. Btw, the etymology you give from Garnier's paper is for *facundus*, not *fecundus*.

Comment: Interesting. The Oxford Latin Dictionary gives no etymology; it merely says the suffix is used to indicate "capacity or inclination".

Comment: [What's a cundus with you?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDJehCXMKwI&t=3m8s)

Answer (score 5):

The common ending *-bundus*, similar meaning, (see [Logeion entry for *pudibundus*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/pudibundus), toggling the left-hand column switch to "Inverse") also suggests that De Vaan has it right, the suffix is just *-undus*.